# Display results horizontally without creating summary table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with 9 columns.  When I do an insert to the table, it inserts 14 rows. (answers to 14 questions).

What I'm trying to accomplish is to display the data horizontally.

This is how data is returned when I do a select statement

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 where UID = '00000'
```

[image]

Each `UID` will have 14 questions and answers. Some could be empty.

What I want to do is display this data in the horizontal format.

Most columns are the same except Answers and questions will change.

So what I want to display is when I do a `select` statement for particular `UID` is to display first entire first row + `questions` and `answers` from other rows in the first row.

I was able to accomplish this using summary table, but I want to find a simpler solution where I don't have to create other tables, maybe I just need a view where I could pull data from.

I need that output for reporting purposes.

Comment: It sounds like you want to PIVOT. This should get you pointed in the right direction: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: I have read few examples on PIVOT. But every example I looked at they are either using `SUM` or `AVERAGE` on a particular column. I don't have a field where I could do average or sum...

Comment: I think it just needs an aggregate, in the case there is only one value MAX usually works just fine.

Comment: I'm using `MAX` right now, but it still not returning me what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something along the lines of

```
SELECT 
UID,
MAX([Abid]) AS [Abid], 
MAX([Date]) As [Date], 
Max([Name]) AS [Name], 
Max([No]) AS [No], 
Max([CName]) AS [CName],
MAX(CASE WHEN [QID]=1 THEN [Questions] ELSE NULL END) AS Question1,
MAX(CASE WHEN [QID]=1 THEN [Answers]   ELSE NULL END) AS Answer1,
MAX(CASE WHEN [QID]=2 THEN [Questions] ELSE NULL END) AS Question2,
MAX(CASE WHEN [QID]=2 THEN [Answers]   ELSE NULL END) AS Answer2,
MAX(CASE WHEN [QID]=3 THEN [Questions] ELSE NULL END) AS Question3,
MAX(CASE WHEN [QID]=3 THEN [Answers]   ELSE NULL END) AS Answer3,
MAX(CASE WHEN [QID]=4 THEN [Questions] ELSE NULL END) AS Question4,
MAX(CASE WHEN [QID]=4 THEN [Answers]   ELSE NULL END) AS Answer4,

etc...

MAX(CASE WHEN [QID]=14 THEN [Questions] ELSE NULL END) AS Question14,
MAX(CASE WHEN [QID]=14 THEN [Answers]   ELSE NULL END) AS Answer14
FROM Table1
GROUP BY UID
```

Should do it

It'll run faster if you've got an index along the lines of

```
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX TABLE1_UID_QID_IX ON [TABLE1]([QID],[AnswerID])
```

Comment: It works, except it doesn't populate columns Answer1, Answer1...Answer14 etc

Comment: Fixed it. Instead of `CASE WHEN [AnswerID]=1` I used `CASE WHEN [QID]=1` Thank you!

Comment: I did think that I might have guessed wrong when choosing between QID and AnswerID. I've updated the Code to reflect that